# Create VPN Service from my app

Tags: android, vpn

I developed an e-wallet for Android platforms. And we're in talks with some cab companies and carriers to provide free data to users who use our application.

The flow will be like this:

1. The cab driver will have a blutooth beacon in their car that will be broadcasting.
2. The user enters the cab, and the app detects and connects to the beacon.
3. Then the application sets up a vpn service and reroutes all cellular data to the vpn so that the user has free cellular data while riding the cab.
4. Once the user gets off the cab and the app no longer detects the beacon, the vpn will be shut down until the user uses a cab that works the same way.

Here are my questions: 
How can I create a VPN programmatically and without any third party app that does what I described in the step 3?
Can I use the VpnService class already provided by the SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your app idea is great! I've worked on similar requirement in past. I had to use 3rd party VPN service to provide secure VPN data network. You can try https://www.myip.io/index.php services. Myip.io is best VPN provider for developers.

Cheers!